# Text doesn't align center vertically in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to center vertically some Text elements inside a View in React Native:

```
export const MainScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const {translations} = useContext(LocalizationContext);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>Ecco come fare per associare StrongAuth</Text>
            <Text style={styles.item}>Visualizza sul tuo computer il processo di autenticazione e accesso al profilo
                aziendale</Text>
            <Text style={styles.item}>Crea il tuo PIN che utilizzerai per i prossimi accessi</Text>
            <Text style={styles.item}>Dopo la conferma, segui la procedura guidata'</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    itemTitle: {
        flex: 2,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: '700'
    },
    item: {
        flex: 1,
        fontSize: 18,
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work, I tried many solutions found around the Web, but nothing happens, I still get this:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be wrapping your `<Text />` components with `<View />` and then setting the flex property to those views. `<Text />` doesn't work with a majority of the layout properties.